# How to encrypte password using MD5 spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, md5

this is my code :

```
PasswordEncoder encoder = new Md5PasswordEncoder();
String hashedPass = encoder.encodePassword("passwordTest", null);
```

THis is my pom.xml file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But I got this error:

```
Md5PasswordEncoder cannot be resolved to a type
```

and :

```
The import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding cannot be resolved
```

Comment: You can't encrypt something with a hash. You can hash a password, but please use something like SHA-3, not MD5

Comment: @JCWasmx86 Thanks but i want to use MD5 of spring security

Comment: It looks like you only did `import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding`, try using `import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder`

Comment: Use `org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder` which can be used for different types of algorithm. It uses bcrypt by default but supports LDAP,MD4, MD5,SHA-1,SHA-256,SHA256 etc.

Comment: @JCWasmx86 i did but I got this error : The import org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding cannot be resolved

Comment: @Amitkumar but i still have this essue: Md5PasswordEncoder cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: You need to add `spring-security-crypto` dependency for it to work!

Comment: @Amitkumar I did

Answer (score 0):

**Old authentication PasswordEncoder interface is deprecated** :

```
package org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding;

@Deprecated
public interface PasswordEncoder {}
```

You should use :

```
package org.springframework.security.crypto.password;

//Implementation : BCryptPasswordEncoder
public interface PasswordEncoder {}
```

This use case used `BCryptPasswordEncoder` to hash a password “xxxxxx”.

```
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        String password = "xxxxxx";
        BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String hashedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(password);

        System.out.println(hashedPassword);
        i++;
    }

  }
}
```